# Validate datetime input for scheduling

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a scheduling system school project,
I need to create a function that validates the date entered by the user,
check if it is 2 days ahead, not Sunday and it is between working hours.

Im using codeigniter framework.

```
//my controller looks like this:
public function checkDateTimeInput(){
        $dateTimeInput = $this->input->post('dateTimeInput');
        if($dateTimeInput /*Greater than 2 days or more*/ && /*not sunday*/ && /*between 8AM-5PM*/){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }



//in my view:
<?php echo form_open('schedules/checkDateTimeInput'); ?>
    <input type="datetime-local" name="dateTimeInput">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completion's sake, I'm going to consider `<input type="datetime-local" name="dateTimeInput">` as the input.

So this basically creates this format:

```
d/m/Y h:i A
```

I tried it on my browser (Chrome) and it does that. More info here also:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local

So taking that into consideration, you can use `createFromFormat` to parse the input and use `DateTime` class.

```
$input = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i A', $dateTimeInput);
$dt = new DateTime; // now
if (
    ($input >= $input->setTime(8, 0) && $input <= $input->setTime(17, 0)) && // time is between 8 to 5
    $input->format('l') !== 'Sunday' && // is not sunday
    $dt->diff($input)->d >= 2 // is greater or more than two days

) {
    return true;
}

return false;
```

Here's a sample [output](https://www.tehplayground.com/8oKf3FFcj6bY13Ve)

Sidenote: I should also point out that `type="datetime-local"` **is not supported in Firefox browser** and should consider using a real date time plugin instead. If the user happens to use Firefox, you should prepare a fall back.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below function and call it from your controller.

```
function checkDateConditions( $dateTimeInput ) {
    //Make DateTime Object using the input
    $inputDate = new DateTime( $dateTimeInput );

    //Get the Hour from the Date Input
    $inputHour = $inputDate->format('G');

    //Check Time is between 8AM and 5PM ( 5PM is = 17)
    if( $inputHour < 8 || $inputHour > 17) {
        return false;
    }

    //This Returns 7 for Sunday
    $dayOfWeek = $inputDate->format('N');
    //If its Sunday we return false
    if( $dayOfWeek == 7) {
        return false;
    }

    //Calculate Date Difference
    $now = new DateTime( Date('Y-m-d') );
    $diff =  $inputDate->diff($now);

    //If date difference is greater than 2 days return false
    if( $diff->days > 2 ) {
        return false;
    }
    //If it reaches here it means all conditions are met so retrun true.
    return true;
}
```

Comment: or just use `$inputDate = new DateTime( $dateTimeInput );` altogether in all criteria

Comment: @Kevin Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated answer accordingly.